# Is there a way to change the namespace of an android app or remove it from an internal test?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to change the namespace of an android app or remove it from an internal test on play store?

Background
We are helping a company adding our app with some small changes to their internal mobile platform. One of the steps we made was to change the namespace of the app so it would work for them. For example com.company.appname. Things where taking some time and we were eager to some internal testing of the via our play store login. That worked great but now when the company is trying to publish the app on their internal mobile platform via google play store it’s that the namespace is used some where else.

•   I have tried to remove the app from our internal test play store.
•   I have tried to change the app namespace in our internal test play store. From com.company.appname to com.ourcompany.appname with out any success.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not published and no one has the app installed google play support can delete the application.